# How to put text in front of the answer in a dialog box

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to imitate a certain notification on a Mac using the dialog box of AS. I know how to make a simple dialog box with buttons and such, but I want the box to display text in front of the answering area.

It would be like this:

```
               Name:____________
           Password:____________
```

P.S. Sorry I cant post pictures I need "10 reputation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in pure AppleScript you can't do this.  You're limited to one input field per dialog box.

Comment: Well how about putting text in front of just ONE input field?

Comment: @HopefulScriptMaker I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but you can't do that either with AppleScript.  You can get 'Name' on one line and an input box on the line below, but that's it.  If you want any sort of rich interface you will need to use ASObjC.